# Why is the spotify login not working?

Tags: ios, swift, spotify

I am using the spotify api, and I am getting an error when I try to login. This is the error `-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "spotify-action://" - error: "(null)"`. Below I have included all the necessary code. What am I doing wrong? I am using the latest soptify api version.

sign in

```
let kClientId = "hidden"
let kCallbackURL = "testapp://callback"

@IBAction func loginspotify(sender: AnyObject) {
    let auth = SPTAuth.defaultInstance()
    auth.clientID = kClientId
    auth.redirectURL = NSURL(string: kCallbackURL)
    auth.tokenSwapURL = NSURL(string: kTokenSwapURL)
    auth.tokenRefreshURL = NSURL(string: kTokenRefreshServiceURL)
    auth.requestedScopes = [SPTAuthUserReadPrivateScope,SPTAuthStreamingScope,SPTAuthPlaylistModifyPrivateScope,SPTAuthUserReadEmailScope,SPTAuthUserLibraryModifyScope,SPTAuthUserLibraryReadScope,SPTAuthPlaylistReadPrivateScope,SPTAuthUserReadPrivateScope]
    var loginURL = auth.loginURL
    print(loginURL)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(loginURL)


}
```

AppDelegate

```
let kClientId = "hidden"
let kCallbackURL = "testapp://callback"

func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    if(SPTAuth.defaultInstance().canHandleURL(url)){
        SPTAuth.defaultInstance().handleAuthCallbackWithTriggeredAuthURL(url, callback: {(error: NSError!, session: SPTSession!) -> Void in
            if(error != nil){
                print("AUTHENTICATION ERROR \(error)")
                return
            }

            let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            let sessionData = NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(session, toFile: "sessiondata")
            userDefaults.setObject(sessionData, forKey: "SpotifySession")
            userDefaults.synchronize()
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("loginSuccessful", object: nil)

        })
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a separate Swap Token server running that hashes a shared secret with your Spotify credentials.  This is required as part of the RC5 standard.

Here is an example of a swap service:

https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk/blob/master/Demo%20Projects/spotify_token_swap.rb

Comment: According to spotify it doesnt seem to mention anything about a swap service

Comment: Take a look at this page: https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-ios-sdk/tutorial/